# df.where not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create a flag variable using:

```
df.where(((df['MOSL_Rating'] == 'Highly Effective') & (df['MOTP_Rating'] == 'Developing')) | ((df['MOSL_Rating'] == 'Highly Effective') & (df['MOTP_Rating'] == 'Ineffective')) | ((df['MOSL_Rating'] == 'Effective') & (df['MOTP_Rating'] == 'Ineffective')) | ((df['MOSL_Rating'] == 'Ineffective') & (df['MOTP_Rating'] == 'Highly Effective')) | ((df['MOSL_Rating'] == 'Ineffective') & (df['MOTP_Rating'] == 'Effective')) | ((df['MOSL_Rating'] == 'Developing') & (df['MOTP_Rating'] == 'Highly Effective')), df['disp_rating'], 1, axis=1)
```

but this returns `ValueError: For argument "inplace" expected type bool, received type int.`

If I change my code from `df['disp_rating'], 1, axis=1` to `df['disp_rating'], True, axis=1` it returns
`TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value`

I've also tried np.where but have gotten similar errors.

I'm clearly missing something here.  Is there a better way to do this?

edit: I've read this post as well, as it was flagged as a possible duplicate.  However, I don't understand how the answer solves my problem since that is about comparing 2 dataframes and doesn't discuss at all how to use this to create a new variable using data from only a single dataframe.

Comment: That is np.where..

Comment: @Wen - I tried np.where but got similar errors.  I also read through the documentation and couldn't figure out how to make it work.  How would you use np.where in this situation?